# SQL query in PHP, Joining a table with two columns which are the same foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

So i need to join 5 tables. One of which I have a problem with. It has 2 columns that are the same foreign key of a different table ie.

```
matchdetail  
idmatch | idplayer1 | idplayer2 | time | (FK) idmatchnight (FK)
```

It is a junction table between

```
player
(PK) idplayer | firstname | secondname | nationality 

matchnight
(PK) idmatchnight | location
```

What should my sql query be ?

My current code : doent work

```
SELECT * FROM player
INNER JOIN coach ON player.idcoach = coach.idcoach
INNER JOIN sponsor ON player.idsponsor = sponsor.idsponsor
INNER JOIN matchdetail ON player.idplayer = matchdetail.idplayer1
                                        AND player.idplayer = matchdetail.idplayer2
INNER JOIN matchnight ON matchdetail.idmatch
WHERE player.idplayer=:idplayer
;"
```

idmatch is a surrogate primary key instead of a composite key

Answer (score 1):

It'd probably be better to re-write your query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM matchdetail
INNER JOIN player AS p1 ON matchdetail.player1=p1.idplayer
INNER JOIN player AS p2 on matchdetail.player2=p2.idplayer
etc...
```

Your current join would basically only allow matches where players played THEMSELVES. By joining `player` twice, you can get the details for the two different players.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep this logic, you can also use OR instead of AND:

```
SELECT * FROM player
INNER JOIN coach ON player.idcoach = coach.idcoach
INNER JOIN sponsor ON player.idsponsor = sponsor.idsponsor
INNER JOIN matchdetail ON (player.idplayer = matchdetail.idplayer1
                                        OR player.idplayer = matchdetail.idplayer2)
INNER JOIN matchnight ON matchdetail.idmatch
WHERE player.idplayer=:idplayer;
```

The problem is that with your current predicate (with AND) it's basically the same as:

```
player.idplayer = matchdetail.idplayer1 = matchdetail.idplayer2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columns, you, actually, want 
  FROM matchnight m
  JOIN matchdetail d
    ON d.idmatchnight = m.idmatchnight
  JOIN player p1
    ON p1.idplayer = d.idplayer1
  JOIN player p2
    ON p2.idplayer = c.idplayer2;
```

Comment: A little explanation goes a long way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your answers everyone

i found a solution myself :)

```
SELECT * FROM matchdetail
INNER JOIN boxer ON matchdetail.idplayer1
                    AND matchdetail.idplayer2
INNER JOIN coach ON player.idcoach = coach.idcoach
INNER JOIN sponsor ON player.idsponsor = sponsor.idsponsor
INNER JOIN matchnight ON matchdetail.idmatchnight = matchnight.idmatchnight
WHERE player.idplayer
```